# Url Rewrite Module Doesn't Redirect

Tags: iis, url-rewrite-module

I have set up an inbound rule in the IIS URL Rewrite module, but it is not working.

Here's my setup.

[image]

What I want is to say that if the user's browser navigates to a.b.com (the first rubbed out part - oh and of course it's not literally "a.b.com" but something else of that form) then he should be redirected to http://www.d.com/foo (the second rubbed out part).

I've used the the Test Pattern feature and it does match correctly.

Comment: Wow, no one knows much about the Rewrite module I see.

Comment: Did you figure it out? We don't have too much information here :)

Comment: Almost pointless to put up a screenshot where your pattern is obfuscated. Could have at least replaced the values with example ones. Otherwise, it's almost useless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have to set a condition to make it work.

Is it a wildcard, exact match, or regex pattern? That will also determine which things you will need to make it work

In your case you can just use the wildcard matching and it should work.